# I have written a code in C but it is not working?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop, primes

**Problem: Write a program in C to find prime numbers from an array.**

I have written a code but it is not working. Would you please help me find where is the problem?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, count = 0, x = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int numbers[n], prime[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 2; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (numbers[i] % j == 0)
            {
                x++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (x > 0)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            prime[count] = numbers[i];
            count++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", prime[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Please help me to find the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't reset `x` (as the counter). You need to set it to 0 for each iteration of `i`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want to check a prime number you should do it for all the values in the range `2,(value-1)`, in order to do that you should correct your second loop as follows:

```
    x = 0; // reset the counter
    for (int j = 2; j < numbers[i]; j++) { // corrected loop
         /* do your checks */
    }    

    /* EDIT: previous code was wrong as suggested in the comments */
    if (x==0 && numbers[i]!=1 && numbers[i]!=0) { // added to avoid 0 and 1 as prime nums
        /* store value */
    }
```

Comment: @SatyajitRoy It is not a good behavior to change your accepted answer after you read my answer..

Comment: Actually I tried to delete it because I was wrong, since I was considering 1 as a prime number, but I couldn't since it's already accepted. Btw It has nothing to do with your answer, I just realized that 1 is not a prime number.

Comment: @MatteoPinna Reading my answer you realized that the inner loop is incorrect.:)

Comment: What? I posted the inner loop corrected as it is now 1 hour ago, the only thing I added is the if check so It doesn't consider 1 as a prime number.

Comment: @MatteoPinna Your changes of the answer does not make the code correct. For example 0 is also not a prime number,:)

Comment: Yeah you're right, but don't say I corrected the inner loop after reading your answer because it's not true :). Hopefully the author reads this and will change the accepted answer to yours.

Comment: @MatteoPinna I do not bother about the best answer. I only try to provide good answers.:)

Answer (score 0):

Your program does not make a great sense.

For starters the declared array should have the element type `unsigned int` instead of `int`.

As the user can enter arbitrary numbers in the array then this loop

```
for (int j = 2; j < n; j++)
```

does not make a sense.

For example if `numbers[0]` is equal to `2` then your program will not consider this number as a prime number though `2` is a prime number.

Moreover you forgot to reinitialize the variable `x` before the inner for loop.

There is no need to define a second array to output prime numbers in the first array.

The program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    size_t n;
    
    if ( scanf( "%zu", &n ) == 1 && n != 0 )
    {
        unsigned int numbers[n];
        
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            scanf( "%u", numbers + i );
        }
        
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            int prime = numbers[i] % 2 == 0 ? numbers[i] == 2 : numbers[i] != 1;
            
            for ( unsigned int j = 3; prime && j <= numbers[i] / j; j +=2 )
            {
                prime = numbers[i] % j != 0;
            }
            
            if ( prime ) printf( "%u ", numbers[i] );
        }
        
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

If the input is

```
25
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

then the output will be

```
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23
```

Comment: @MatteoPinna You are wrong. numbers[0] equal to 2 is considered as a non prime number.

Comment: If he resets x to 0 and changes the loop stop condition to j<numbers[i], it does count it.

Comment: @MatteoPinna Why are you writing this me? I pointed out all these drawbacks of his program in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use a booleen function to check if the number is prime or not

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool Prime(int);

int main()
{
int N;
do
{
   printf("Give me the number of numbers :");
   scanf("%d",&N);
}while(N<1);//in your array must be minimum 1 element
int prime[N];
int arr[N];
int j=0;

for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
   do
   {
       printf("Enter a number %d:",i+1);
       scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
   }while(arr[i]<0); 

   if(arr[i]!=1&&arr[i]!=0&&Prime(arr[i])==true)
   {
      prime[j]=arr[i];
      j++;
   }
}
  printf("\nListe of prime number :\n\n");

  for(int p=0;p<j;p++)
  {
      printf("[%d]",prime[p]);
  }

  printf("\n\n");
  return 0;
}


bool Prime(int n)
{
  for(int i=2;i<=(n/2);i++)
  {
      if(n%i==0)
      {
          return false;
      }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take of some notes before we dig into the issue :
Instead of typing

```
if (x>0) { 
  }
else
//your code
```

This can be directly be

```
if (x<=0)
 //your code
```

If a for loop includes 1 instruction you dont need to open {}
So instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
}
```

You can type directly

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
```

Also i have noticed that you declared a variable n then used it to declare the size of an array . Thats wrong .
You need to use malloc to have a dynamic array to do the same function u asked for . Otherwise , use a static array and limit the n in its boundries.
Read more about pointers.
About the issue of your code , answers above already handled the issue .